# Using only stored procedures to query database in ASP.NET web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

My question is not how to achieve that but what kind of approach is this. I'm to maintain and (if I can) add new features to an existing web application which is about 6-7 years old and for first time I see such a thing which for me seems kind of ridiculous.

So I have about 220 stored procedures, 70 user defined functions (on the MS SQL 2008 Server) and I'm talking about relatively small to medium application. In the business logic there is not a single line of code containing `SQL` or something made to query and perform some kind of `CRUD`. In fact the idea is every query to the database to be performed using a stored procedure.

Just an example : this is a method from a class that is more than 10,000 rows, as it seems it's used to call a stored procedure:

```
public static int GridViewAdd(param1, param2..)//the names are changed 
    {

        SqlConnection myConnection = GetSqlConnection();
        SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = GetSqlDataAdapterSP(procName, myConnection);

        // Set the parameters of the stored procedure:

        myDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50));
        myDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters["@Name"].Value = name;

        //more parameters..

        myConnection.Open();
        try
        {
            myDataAdapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            result = Convert.ToInt32(myDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters["@ID"].Value);
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlex)
        {
            throw new Exception(SqlErrors.InterpretError(sqlex.Message));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            myDataAdapter.Dispose();
            myConnection.Close();
        }
        return result;
     }
```

In my database inside `programmability` -> `Stored Procedures` I have a stored procedure with this name so I guess this is how I call the procedure from inside my code (in Visual Studio 2012).

However I don't have a lot of experience as programmer at all and the whole time I've been using `Entity Framework` mostly with `Code First` workflow and now this looks like a huge mess to me. I tried to search the web for some examples and/or explanation what is this approach, how its working and so on and I get to this article [Creating Stored Procedures and User-Defined Functions with Managed Code](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/advanced-data-access-scenarios/creating-stored-procedures-and-user-defined-functions-with-managed-code-cs)  where the stuff described seems closest to what I'm seeing in my code. But still can you help me with identifying exactly what is this approach (if additional info is needed please ask), and maybe some guidelines and/or articles about using it because right now I see the code but I definitely have difficulties understanding how the things are happening (I mean creating a new query/sp, calling it from my code, do I need to know `T-SQL` in order to write correctly my sp or as it's said in the article above I can write standard C# methods and leave the CLR take care for the rest..) and all the stuff that would help me to understand how exactly am I supposed to work having this legacy and being allowed only to build upon it but not changing the conception.

Comment: That file might be auto-generated from the stored procedures in the database.  It looks like mindless boilerplate code to allow some higher layer to call stored procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just using simple ADO.NET to perform the execution of a Stored Procedure.  Stored procedures are written (for SQL Server) via T-SQL, so yes you need to understand/write T-SQL to modify the procedure.  Here is the landing page for ADO.NET on MSDN, you should be able to get a better idea of how things are working reading through this.  Also you should be able to find something on stored procedure execution.  Just remember, Entity Framework is an abstraction on top of ADO.NET.  Everything you are using in Code First has ADO.NET underpinnings to make the "magic" happen.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx(v=vs.110).aspx

Here is another tutorial specifically for calling SPs:

http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson07